# npm solc: Assertion error [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid call back

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.
    at wrapCallback (C:\Users\mouazzamj058\solc_example\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:16:5)
    at runWithReadCallback (C:\Users\mouazzamj058\solc_example\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:37:42)
    at compileStandard (C:\Users\mouazzamj058\solc_example\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:78:14)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper (C:\Users\mouazzamj058\solc_example\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:85:14)
    at Object. (C:\Users\mouazzamj058\solc_example\example.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Comment: It would help if you provided a more clear issue. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

First you write:

> npm uninstall solc

then write

> npm install solc@0.4.25